# Processing multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, processing

Hey I can't get processing to run my code due to a NullPointerException on my array value in the println statement.

```
for (bx=0; bx<=7; bx++) {
    for (by=0; by<=4; by++) {
        rect(bx*BRICK_WIDTH, by*BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT); 
        int[][] a = {{bx}, {by}};
    }
    println (a[bx][by]);
}
```

Comment: Please tag with the language you are using (I don't recognize it).  My guess is that `println (a [bx] [by])` is the culprit.  In most programming languages, arrays are zero-based, meaning that a 1D array of length 5 would have addressable indices of 0 through 4, inclusive, excluding 5.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just did it thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand the indices issue that you bring up but I think it's more likely that I'm initializing the array incorrectly. That being said I will run any suggestion in my code and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the time

Comment: Look at your updated code.  The `a[][]` array is out of scope when you print inside the outer most loop.  Do you see it?  You can't reference `a[][]` because it doesn't exist there.

Comment: Pre-emptive: I know that it is wildly poor form to include a println statement inside of a for loop but that was the only way I could get my code formatted correctly for the question. I did NOT run my code that way

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried stating the array as a top level variable to no avail :(

Comment: You need to narrow your code down to a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. It's impossible for us to help you if you only give us a disconnected snippet that we can't actually run. Note that this should **not** be your entire program either! Please [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) and narrow your problem down to a small example program. Good luck.

Comment: `println (a[bx][by]);` in this case is not initialize since you put it outside the second loop. Because it is making `by = 5`. You should put it inside the second loop or just `println (a[bx][by- 1]);` to print the last element of `a[bx]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From just the code you posted, I wouldn't expect you to get a `NullPointerException`. I would expect you to get a `The variable "a" does not exist` error.

So I'm guessing that you have another `a` variable at the top of your sketch, like this:

```
int[][] a;

void draw(){
  for (bx=0; bx<=7; bx++) {
    for (by=0; by<=4; by++) {
        rect(bx*BRICK_WIDTH, by*BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT); 
        int[][] a = {{bx}, {by}};
    }
    println (a[bx][by]);
  }
}
```

Please note that this is why it's so important for you to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we don't have to guess at what your code is doing.

If this is the case, your problem is caused because the `int[][] a = {{bx}, {by}};` line inside the `for` loop is declaring a **different** variable with the same name. It's not touching the skethc-level `a` variable. So the sketch-level `a` variable still has the default value of `null`, hence the `NullPointerException` when you try to use it.

Also note that it doesn't make a ton of sense to assign `a` to anything inside the `for` loop. To see why, consider this simpler example:

```
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  x = i;
}
println(x);
```

You'll see that the `x` variable only "keeps" the last value we assigned to it. The same thing is true of arrays. Maybe you meant to set a particular **index** of your array?

If you're still having trouble then please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.